# Typescript with Polymer

Tags: typescript, polymer

I know that there have been other questions on this topic but none of the answers have been particularly helpful and some are out of date so I thought I would ask again.

Has anyone had any luck with getting Polymer and Typescript to play nice? It seems like its very almost there, ideally we want to supply a class instance or prototype to polymer then it takes care of the rest.

For example given the following:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="color">
    <template>       
        Hello there <strong>{{name}}</strong>
        <button on-click="{{setFocus}}">Set focus to text input</button>
    </template>
    <script src="my-element.js"></script>    
</polymer-element>
```

If we do this:

```
class MyElement {
    name = "Mike";
    setFocus() {
        console.log("called");        
    }
}
Polymer(new MyElement());
```

Then we get "name" outputted correctly but clicking the button does not call the function.

However if we do this:

```
class MyElement {
    name = "Mike";
    setFocus() {
        console.log("called");        
    }
}
Polymer(MyElement.prototype);
```

Then we get the console output when we click the button but the variable is undefined.

Anyone have any clue how we get these to play nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default field values are set in the constructor, but when you pass the prototype to `Polymer()` it doesn't have access to the constructor.

Instead, set default values in the `created` callback. It's a bit of a hack, but it's not limited to just Typescript, I've run into the same thing writing closure-compiler style classes for use as polymer elements.

```
class MyElement {
    name : string;
    created() {
      this.name = "Mike";
    }
    setFocus() {
        console.log("called");        
    }
}
Polymer(MyElement.prototype);
```

Comment: How would you go about accessing the "this." variables such as "this.$.el" and so on?

Comment: Scratch that, you can do this: class MyPolymerElement {
    $: any;
}class MyElement extends MyPolymerElement {}

Comment: What we're doing with Closure Compiler is defining a base class for polymer elements that extends HTMLElement. You could generate a .d.ts from this .externs.js in a pretty straightforwards way I think (maybe automatically?): https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/polymer.externs.js

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library to handle just this, check https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS, but works only with the new Polymer (>=1.0 that is).

Comment: **PolymerTS** is very helpful to work with Polymer using Typescript.  I wrote also a Yeoman generator  **[generator-polymerts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-polymerts)** to make easier work with it